# Minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I am stuck trying to find the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I have tried using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3859772/758031) method and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3859794/758031) method but none of them seem to be working in this case. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Put $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} - 1=\sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} + 1 - 2 =\frac{(\sqrt[3]{3})^3-1}{\sqrt[3]{3}-1}-2 = \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{3}-1}-2$, and hence $\sqrt[3]{3}=2/(\alpha+2)+1=\frac{\alpha+4}{\alpha+2}$. So $\alpha$ is root of $3(x+2)^3-(x+4)^3=2(x^3+3x^2-6x-20)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's work in $\mathbb Q( \sqrt[3]{3})$. Since $x^3-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, a basis for $\mathbb Q( \sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\{1,\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{9}\}$.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} - 1$. The matrix of the $\mathbb Q$-linear map $x \mapsto \alpha x$ in the basis $\{1,\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{9}\}$ is
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & \hphantom-3 & \hphantom-3 \\ \hphantom-1 & -1 & \hphantom-3 \\ \hphantom-1 & \hphantom-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The set of rational polynomials that kill $A$ and the set of rational polynomials that kill $\alpha$ are exactly the same. In particular, the minimum polynomial of $A$ is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$.

Now, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\chi(x)=x^3+3x^2-6x-20$. Since it has no rational roots, $\chi$ is irreducible. Since the characteristic and minimum polynomials of $A$ share the same irreducible factors, $\chi$ is the minimum polynomial of $A$, hence of $\alpha$.

Comment: I like this method, but I want to explain a bit about what is going on.  Call the matrix $A$, and its characteristic polynomial $p(x)$..  For any polynomial $f(x)$, we have that $f(A)$ acts on the basis as multiplication by $f(\alpha)$.  By Cayley Hamilton, $p(A)=0$, so multiplication by $p(\alpha)$ sends each of the basis elements to $0$.  Thus, $p(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for adding an explanation.

Comment: This is the surest way of doing problems like this: it always works.

Comment: Right, but you miss the proof of a quite non trivial fact: that $1, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{9}$ is indeed a base. Good method though.

Comment: @lhf I think this is very elegant but I don't fully understand why the characteristic has a relation with the minimum polynomial

Comment: @fdez,  see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt[3]9+\sqrt[3]3-1=x.$

Now, by using $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$ and since $3\neq9,$ it's equivalent to
$$9+3-(x+1)^3+3\sqrt[3]{27}(x+1)=0$$ or
$$x^3+3x^2-6x-20=0,$$ which has no integer roots and from  here has no rational roots.

Answer (score 1):

First let us find a polynomial that vanished on that number. Notice that
$$
   \alpha = \sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3} - 1
   \; \Rightarrow \;
   (\alpha + 1)^3 = (\sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3})^3 = 9 + 9 \sqrt[3]{3} + 9 \sqrt[3]{9} + 3 =
   12 + 9(\alpha + 1)
$$
where the last equation follows trivially as $\alpha + 1 = \sqrt[3]{9} + \sqrt[3]{3}$. So we know that $(x + 1)^3 - 9(x + 1) - 12$ is divided by the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$. Next step is to observe that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it has no rational roots, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Rtight, thank for pointing that up!